# Keyboard accessible hover menu ul class problems with list-style-type

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use this keyboard accessible hover menu in my site: https://codepen.io/una/pen/eMaBgX.

The problem is that it messes the sites other unordered lists styles by not showing them right even though I have selected it to only use the `<ul class="dropdown">`.

It doesn't show them right either in menu as it selected to show in `.dropdown ul { list-style-type: none;` as it shows the discs as list-style-type. If it's only: `ul { list-style-type: none; }` it shows in right in menu but messes the other unordered lists in my site.

My codepen for this menu:

https://codepen.io/l_h/pen/ZEBemQj

Answer (score 0):

you have so specify your `ul` selection a little bit more. In this case, u style every ul in your code, like you mentioned.

You could add before every `ul` and `li` styling a `nav` so you style only the `nav ul li` elements, like this (i added a `list-style-type` to `nav li` for hiding the bullet points):

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
nav {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 65px !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}
ul {
  color: white;
}

nav .dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 125%;
}

 nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
   
/* i added this */
   list-style-type: none;
}
 
nav .listitem li { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  text-align: left;
  margin:0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav li .listitem a {
  color:#ec7335;
  font-weight: 400;

}

nav li .listitem a:hover {
  color:#3A3A3F
}

 nav  ul li ul {
  background-color: #fff;
  color:black;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 300ms ease opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul,
nav ul li:focus-within > ul,
nav ul li ul:hover,
nav ul li ul:focus {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Kotia etsimässä</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Täytä hakemus</a>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Kiinteistömme</a></li></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Asunto juuri sinulle</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Omatoimiremontti</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Tuettu asuminen</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Vuokravakuus</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Haapajärvi asuinalueena</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Asukkaalle</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="listitem"><a href="">Asumisen ABC</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Järjestyssäännöt</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Pelastussuunnitelma</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Jätteiden lajittelu</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Sisäänmuuttavalle</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Asunnon irtisanominen</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Pois muuttavalle</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Yhteystiedot</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="listitem"><a href="">Yhteyshenkilöt</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Vikailmoituslomake</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Isännöinti</a></li>
        <li class="listitem"><a href="">Sähköiset laskutustiedot</a></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<ul>
 <li>My list 1</li>
 <li>My list 2</li>
</ul>
```